# Creating files with some content with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to configure a server with a few files and I want to do it programmatically.

I need to create files say  `/home/a.config, /var/spool/b.config, /etc/c.config`

Files above have some contents (multi lines).

I want to create ONE shell script which can create all three file with multiple lines (around 10).
I would like to know the how can I use `CAT` command to do that. (inside shell script).

I am looking something like this

```
echo " going to create  /home/a.config"

cat "HOW CAN I HAVE MULTIPLE LINES HERE?? " >  /home/a.config
```

thanks

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

```
cat <<EOF >filename
first line
second line
third line
EOF
```

You can place several of these in the same script.

Comment: Note that `$` has to be escaped if it's to be included in the actual text.

Comment: @Nagev: If you don't want any parameter expansion, command substitution, and  arithmetic  expansion in the here document you can quote the beginning delimiter `'EOF'` instead of having to escape each individual dollar sign.

Comment: And if I want to use a parameter value in my text?

Comment: How do I access an external variable?

Comment: @JúlioFalbo: If you don't quote the here doc delimiter (e.g. `EOF`) then parameters (variables) in the text will be expanded.

Comment: @BraianCoronel: I don't know what you mean by external variable. But see my immediately preceding comment to see if it's helpful.

Answer (score 32):

```
file="/tmp/test.txt"
echo "Adding first line" > $file
echo "Adding first line replaced" > $file
echo "Appending second line " >> $file
echo "Appending third line" >> $file
cat $file
```

**>** to add/replace the content ( here actual content got replaced by the 2nd line)
**>>** to append

**Result**
Adding first line  replaced
Appending second line
Appending third line

Comment: I wonder why no one gave you an up vote. Your answer is pretty good too. Thanks works for me.

Comment: I thought that your answer is pretty much spot on...

Answer (score 11):

Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="your text"
echo "simply put,
just so: $var" > a.config
```

For further info, see Input/Output part of [abs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html).
Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 7):

If you've got variables like $1 or $HOMEDIR in your text then these normally get evaluated and substituted with actual values. If you want to prevent these from getting substituted then you need to quote the opening limit string (EOF in example below) with single quote `'EOF'`, double quote `"EOF"` or precede it with backslash `\EOF`

Closing limit string stays as is. `EOF`

This is especially useful if you are writing shell scripts to a file.

```
cat << 'EOF' >/etc/rc.d/init.d/startup
case $1 in
    start)
        start 
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    status)
       pid=$(tomcat_pid)
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
        then
           echo "Tomcat is running with pid: $pid"
        else
           echo "Tomcat is not running"
        fi
        ;;
esac

EOF
```

Refer Example 19.7 Parameter Substitution Turned off in [Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: Perfect ! this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
>\#!/bin/bash
>
>var="your text" <br>
>echo "simply put, <br>
>just so: $var" > a.config
```

Note that you also need to escape out certain characters to avoid them interfering with what you're trying to do, for example $ ` and " will all break such a statement unless preceded with a backslash, i.e. \`  \$  or  \"

so if we define the following:

> var="100"

the following would not behave as expected:

> echo "simply put, 
>   just "lend" me US$ $var" > a.config

but the following would work correctly:

> echo "simply put, 
>   just \"lend\" me US\$ $var" > a.config

Answer (score 0):

I would use `tee` command like this:

```
echo "My 
long
multiline
text
here!
" | sudo tee -a /etc/config.conf
```